# $f(x,y)= Ax +By +Cxy +D$. if $f(x,y)=\frac 1{xy}$ for $x,y \in \{3,4\}$, then $f(5,5)=?$

Tags: functions, polynomials, linear-transformations

> Let $f(x,y)= Ax +By +Cxy +D$. if $f(x,y)=\frac 1{xy}$ for $x,y \in \{3,4\}$,
> then what is the value of $f(5,5)$?

Here in this question I tried substituting $y=x$ thus giving :

$f(x,x) = \frac {1}{x^2}$ for $x \in \{3,4\}$

where $f(x,x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree 2. So $x^2f(x,x)$ should be a polynomial of degree 4.

$\implies$ $x^2f(x,x)-1 = k(x-3)^2(x-4)^2$

Putting $x=0$ in the eqn gives :

$k=\frac {-1}{144}$

Putting $x=5$ in eqn gives :

$f(5,5) = \frac 7{180}$

But the answer given is :

$f(5,5) = \frac1{36}$

I cant find the mistake so it will be good if someone points out the mistake and provides a correct solution too for the question.

Comment: The problem is worded strangely.  To say that $f(x,y)$ is linear in $x,y$ ought to mean that $f(x,y)=Ax+By+C$ for constants $A,B,C$.  The condition on $f(x,y)=\frac 1{xy}$  only holds for $x,y\in \{3,4\}$.  Use that information to compute $A,B,C$.

Comment: @lulu well this question was a part of the paragraph on linear functions in many variables which said that linear functions mean that the degree of x and y both is 1 so,
$f(x,y) = Ax +By +Cxy + D$

Comment: $xy$ is not a linear term...that's not a linear function, it's quadratic.  Worth noting, though, that there are no linear functions that satisfy the conditions.

Comment: @lulu the function is not a compeletely linear function but linear in x and linear in y thats waht i am saying

Comment: I suggest editing the question to include the functional form you want.  Still just a matter of solving for coefficients.

Comment: @lulu i think now its good?

Comment: And, now there is a unique solution.  Helps to note that symmetry tells us that $A=B$, so there are really only three variables here.

Comment: To stress:  you have no information about $f(x,x)$ other than at the two points $x\in \{3,4\}$ so the quartic you produce isn't relevant.

Comment: When a function of 2 variables $x$ & $y$ is linear in each variable , then it is called bilinear function [[ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BilinearFunction.html ]] which can contain $xy$ term , while linear function can not contain that term. Here , $f(x,y)$ is indeed bilinear !

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}f(5,5)&=f(3,3)+4f(4,4) - 2\left(f(3,4)+f(4,3)\right) \\& = \frac{1}{3\cdot3}+\frac{4}{4\cdot4}-2\cdot2\cdot\frac{1}{3\cdot4}\\&=\frac{1}{36}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is here:
$$x^2f(x,x)-1 = k(x-3)^2(x-4)^2$$
All you can say is
$$x^2f(x,x)-1 =(x-3)(x-4)Q(x)$$
for some quadratic polynomial $Q$.

Others have already posted correct solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$
\begin{align}
f(3,4)=f(4,3)=\frac{1}{12}\\
f(3,3)=\frac{1}{9}\\
f(4,4)=\frac{1}{16}\\
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
f(x,y)=ax+by+cxy+d
$$
Solving the linear system of equation with your favourite methods yields
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{144}\left(-7x-7y+xy+49\right)
$$
see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=system+equation+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation1%22%7D+-%3E%223a%2B4b%2B12c%2BD%3D1%2F12%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%7D%2C+%22dflt%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation2%22%7D+-%3E%224a%2B3b%2B12c%2BD%3D1%2F12%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation3%22%7D+-%3E%223a%2B3b%2B9c%2BD%3D1%2F9%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22SolveSystemOf4EquationsCalculator%22%2C+%22equation4%22%7D+-%3E%224a%2B4b%2B16c%2BD%3D1%2F16%22)
That yields
$$
f(5,5)=\frac{4}{144}=\frac{1}{36}
$$